# Compare in two columns and add value

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns looking like this:

```
Column 1   Column 2
1             x
x             2
2             2
x             x
1             2
```

I want to do two things;

1. For each row match (row n column 1 = row n column 2) it should mark cell n in column 1 green if there is a match and red if it is not.
2. It should create a sum cell where each match is worth 1 point, in this case column 1 should result in 2 points.

Is this even possible with excel and if so, how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question:

> It should mark cell n in column 1 green if there is a match and red if it is not

You can do this using [Conditional Formatting](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html).

Ex:

Assume column A and column B, with the values starting in row 2.

The following conditional formatting would highlight column A values in green if they match the corresponding value in column B in the same row, otherwise red.

[image: example conditional formatting]

Highlight the values in column A, then apply this conditional formatting.

For the second part of your question

> It should create a sum cell where each match is worth 1 point, in this case column 1 should result in 2 points

The following array formula will tally all the matches and show you how many there are:

**=SUM(IF(A2:A6=B2:B6,1,0))**

Assuming again that we are in columns A & B with your sample data.

Remember to [commit](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/CSE-array-formulas-excel.php) this formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Per comment from [andy holaday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981197/compare-in-two-columns-and-add-value/10982853#comment14356057_10982853), here is another formula that will work:

**=SUMPRODUCT(N(A2:A6=B2:B6))**
or
**=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A6=B2:B6))**

These are not CSE formulas so you would not need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to commit them.

Comment: +1 for thoroughness. For part two an array formula can be avoided with e.g., `=SUMPRODUCT(N(A2:A6=B2:B6))` or `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A6=B2:B6))`